# Configurable product Url Not changing in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, url, url-rewrite

I'm trying to change the URL of my configurable products I have changed the URL through

> Product->search engine->urlkey

But it's not getting effect on the product still loading from old URL

Comment: Have you reindex command?

Comment: ya i have reindexse it